Am I stuck with the Server Side Object Model when developing for on-prem, internet-facing SharePoint?
I'm in a quandary and I can't figure out the best course of action to take.
I need to develop a page that will run on SharePoint Subscription Edition but will be an authenticated internet-facing site. I want a rich user-experience with client-side web parts but I can't use SPFx as the tooling and packages are years and years out of date and our security team won't look kindly upon me if I use 7-year-old packages!
I could develop a "traditional" SPA in something like React and host it inside of a SharePoint page, but then our internet-facing users would need to authenticate twice to access the page: once for the main site and then again for the SPA using OAuth or similar.
Is there anything else like SPFx that I can run inside of the page using the SP context of the user to access SharePoint resources without having to log in twice?
Failing that I guess I'm back to server-side web parts and post-backs!
Thanks for your thoughts.


our security team won't look kindly upon me if I use 7-year-old packages!

SharePoint 2019 "only" receives extended support, currently, and will go out of support in mid 2026. I wouldn't be too keen on exposing that to the internet, regardless of what packages are used.
However, to answer the question: Alternatively to SPFx or the server-side model, you could create a "traditional" SPA, like you suggested, and use the REST api to communicate with SharePoint. That way, the communication to SharePoint will be authenticated, and no additional authentication will be required.

Apparently I spoke out of turn, it's SP SE it's being hosted on. Same thing under the hood I guess, but at least it's in support for a bit longer!
Please forgive my ignorance but surely I still need to authenticate against the REST API, or will it accept the auth cookies from the site and be happy?

If you make the requests from a page, that is itself hosted in SharePoint, no further authentication is needed.
